# Incorrect Next Run on Monthly Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-agent

Users have reported that a job on a recurring schedule has not been firing. This is also evident in the execution history.

After some experimentation, it looks like it might be a bug in the SQL Agent.

If configure the schedule as a **Monthly** recurring job, Day **1** of every **5** month(s) at **12:05 AM**, starting **1-Jan-2024** [image: Schedule1]

... the Job activity Monitor shows the next run as the **1-Mar-2024 12:05 AM** [image: ActivityMonitor1].

If I change the job so it is "The **first** **day** of every **5** month(s)" [image: Schedule2]

... the Job Activity Monitor shows the next run as **01-Jun-2024 12:05 AM** [image: ActivityMonitor2]

Has anyone else experienced this?

I'm running SQL Server 2016 SP3-CU1-GDR.

Comment: When creating a new job with new schedules I see the same behavior, SQL Server 2016 (13.0.6435.1). I don't have any jobs that run once every several months so I can't check an existing job to see if the "day 1" version needs a starting point to base the 5 months off of where the "first day" version knows where 5 months from now is at.

Comment: Can reproduce the same problem on 2019 CU22 using sp_update_schedule directly. Looks like a longer standing issue.